# About Math notation: the set of the first $n$ natural numbers

Tags: notation

Is it true that I can write the set of the the first $n$ natural numbers as $[ n] $?

For example, $[10]= \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \}$. And in which math context this is used?

Comment: It's the set of the first $n$ natural numbers, not of the $n^{\text{th}}$ natural number. This would be $\{n\}$.

Comment: Actually... the $n^{th}$ natural number can be defined as $[n-1]$, so it's almost true.

Comment: @GitGud Why `0` is natural number ? I am not good in math..

Comment: some time `n` natural numbers are shown as `[1-n]` in TOC

Comment: Here's a question. What's more useful? Defining $\{1,...,10\}=[10]$, or defining $\{0,...,9\}=[10]$? And does it depend on context?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan read the first paragraph on the $\textbf{The contemporary standard}$ section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#The_contemporary_standard

Comment: Yes, I wanted to mean the set of the first $n$ natural numbers. The set of the natural numbers, til the $n^{th}$ natural number

Comment: @user18921 I don't think any of the defitions is more useful than the other, one just has to be careful with $[0]$, if it is meant to be defined.

Comment: @GitGud: Actually $[0]=\emptyset$ is the one case where it makes no difference what you define $[n]$ to be. However, as a combinatorialist I can witness that it is much more useful to define $[n]=\{\, i\in\mathbf N\mid i<n\,\} = \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ than the more common $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Also by the former convention and the "contemporary standard" you linked to, one has $\[n]=n$ for all $n\in\mathbf N$, which some might consider cute.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen When I said that one had to be careful with $[0]$, I meant that $0$ might not be considered a natural number, that's all.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen In my opinion, Von Neumann's approach to constructing the natural numbers is merely a "model", and should not be seen as the unique contemporary understanding of what the natural numbers "are." After all, there are other models. However, I'm interested in this comment: "as a combinatorialist I can witness that it is much more useful to define $[n]=\{0,...,n-1\}$" I presume you speak of modular arithemtic? Or do other examples occur? One argument against beginning at $0$ is that sequences with $n$ terms become $(a_0,...,a_{n-1}),$ which is a tad awkward.

Comment: @user18921: "Cute" implies it is not really a serious argument. I do not however speak of mudular arithmetic or positional number systems only. There are unimportant reasons to prefer $1$..$n$ (our childood habit to start counting at $1$, and the "..." notation) and numerous important reasons to prefer $0$..$n-1$. This margin is too narrow to be exhausitve, but consider [$q$-numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog#.22Classical.22_q-theory) $[n]_q=\sum_{i\in[n]}q^i$ or the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) $(X_i^j)_{i,j\in[n]}$ as examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define $[n]$ however you want, so it can be true. Despite that, it is a common notation for the set $\{k\in \mathbb{N} : k\leq n\}$, yes.

This notation is used more often on Elementary Set Theory and Discrete Mathematics. Unfortunately analysts don't use it much. I've never seen it being used in Abstract Algebra or Linear Algebra either.

Comment: N.B. This definition requires asserting that $\mathbb{N}$ begin at $1$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That seems to be the case judging by the OP's question.

Comment: I can certainly attest to analysts not using this notation a lot. I count myself as an analyst, and I have never seen it until now. Why this is unfortunate, I don't know.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Because it's more troublesome to write $\{1, \dots , n\}$ than $[n]$.

Comment: Yes, but I usually have more interesting things to write about. Brief notation is fine, but only if you use it often enough for it to be worth the bother.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen If you talk about the components of vectors or matrices, or anything related to finite sequences, you'll probably find ample uses for this notation.