# What are the main changes between ISO 31-11 and ISO 80000-2? (math notation standards)

Tags: notation

The international standard that defines mathematical signs and symbols, [ISO 31-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11), was superseded in 2009 by [ISO 80000-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2). What are the main changes?

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing!

Comment: @nayrb Yeah that's pretty convenient. Unfortunately the ISO 80000-2 is behind paywall, which is a very nice way to spread a standard...

Comment: I won't pay 140 CHF to help decide when to write $\phi$ and when $\varphi$. And I'll keep writing $\pi$ in italics anyway cause I don't know how to avoid it

Comment: I can't imagine why the very idea puts my back up. Yet, it does. Perhaps it's just too 1984-ish.

Comment: Personally I looked for international standards for math notation when I moved from France to the US. As some notations changed, e.g. an open interval is commonly written ]a, b[ in France vs. (a, b) in the US, I started getting interested in standard notations for at least the most common concepts.

Comment: I don't even know how to get $\pi$ to be upright, no matter what I do— `\rm\pi` $\rm\pi$, `π` $π$, `\rm π` $\rm π$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I've got the document (160 USD for 40 pages!). Here is what it says in page iv:

> The first edition cancels and replaces ISO 31-11:1992, which has been
>   technically revised. The major technical changes from the previous
>   standard are the following:
>
> - Four clauses have been added, i.e. "Standard number sets and intervals", "Elementary geometry", "Combinatorics" and "Transforms".

Interestingly, it goes on saying that the standard's title "Quantities and units — Part 2: Mathematical signs and symbols to be used in the natural sciences and technology" should be renamed into "Quantities and units — Part 2: Mathematics".

Given the amount of copyright notices and other efforts to keep the standard from being diffused, I hope I don't get sued for quoting one sentence...

Comment: What a complete waste of money, Frank!

Comment: I am upvoting this just because you paid that much money for the document.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to find a way to turn upvotes into USD and my investment will finally pay back :-)

Comment: I don't understand how something can become standard if it's hoarded at such an exorbitant price.