# Does an x exist so that there are n amount of pythagorean triples

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Given $n\in\mathbb N$, does there exist an $x\in\mathbb N$, s.t. for $i\in\mathbb N,\;i\leq n$, $\exists y_i,z_i\in\mathbb N$ such that each $y_i$ is distinct and

$$x^2 + y_i^2 = z_i^2$$

Comment: Could you explain the meaning  of "$i\in[n]$"?

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb N$, $[n]$ is notation for $\{i\in\mathbb N\;|\;i\leq n\}$

Comment: @DonThousand Can you give a reference?

Comment: @user [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287251/about-math-notation-the-set-of-the-first-n-natural-numbers)

Comment: @DonThousand But it can be inconvenient for people not used to your math lexicon. Besides I don't find it a good idea to use an overcomplicated notation by editing the questions of other users.

Comment: @user Fair point. I was aiming to make the problem comprehensible, but it seems as though I've leaked my own personal notational biases into the problem.

Comment: Yes there are multiple triples for many values of $A$ and you can find them in my answer about [matching sides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590629/how-to-find-all-pythagorean-triples-containing-a-given-number/3272945#3272945). for example $f(9,4)=(65,72,97)\quad f(33,32)=(65,2112,2113)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes: We know that $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, $x=2^{2n+1},y_i=2^{n+i}-2^{n-i},z_i=2^{n+i}+2^{n-i}$ is a triple for all $i\in\mathbb N,\;i\leq n$.

Comment: How did you get that if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples)